# SVG inside OPTION element

Tags: html, svg, html-select

I am creating the following `svg` element and structure:

```
<svg width="135" height="15">
    <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#ffffe5" x="0" y="0"></rect>
    <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#f7fcb9" x="15" y="0"></rect>
    <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#d9f0a3" x="30" y="0"></rect>
    <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#addd8e" x="45" y="0"></rect>
    <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#78c679" x="60" y="0"></rect>
    <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#41ab5d" x="75" y="0"></rect>
    <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#238443" x="90" y="0"></rect>
    <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#006837" x="105" y="0"></rect>
    <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#004529" x="120" y="0"></rect>
</svg>
```

Which produces a row of little squares. Just like this:

[image]

So far everything is OK.

Then I place the code above inside an `option` for the `select` drop-down, as shown below:

```
<select id="data-color-scheme">
    <option id="YlGn">
        <div>
            <svg width="135" height="15">
                <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#ffffe5" x="0" y="0"></rect>
                <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#f7fcb9" x="15" y="0"></rect>
                <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#d9f0a3" x="30" y="0"></rect>
                <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#addd8e" x="45" y="0"></rect>
                <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#78c679" x="60" y="0"></rect>
                <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#41ab5d" x="75" y="0"></rect>
                <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#238443" x="90" y="0"></rect>
                <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#006837" x="105" y="0"></rect>
                <rect width="15" height="15" fill="#004529" x="120" y="0"></rect>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </option>
</select>
```

Now the content of the `option` is displayed as a white blank, as shown in the image below:

[image]

As you can see, the content of the image is empty. However, if I run the debugging inspector, I can still detect the `svg` element there.

What am I doing wrong? How can I display an `svg` inside an option? Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

HTML `<option>` elements can only contain plain text.

What you are running into is the long-running "How to style a `<select>` element" discussion. To describe all the possible hacks and solutions proposed through the years goes far beyond the scope of an answer here and would be purely opinion-based. Look around for

- CSS hacks that try to override the OS-provided styling
- UI modules for Javascript libraries that emulate the behavior of `<select>` with other elements
- Web Components

and make up your own mind.

Answer (score 1):

Straight answers:

1. Use Emojis though they look different from different browsers and versions
2. Use select2 jquery approach. Install it and use it