# Error: validateDOMNesting(...): <svg> cannot appear as a child of <option> using icon (Wifi) within the input select option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-redux

I am using React in my project and having trouble getting the Wi-Fi Signal Strength Icon next to the networks name. (These two fields come from an external endpoint.)

The error I'm getting in the console (f12) would be this: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a child of . Does anyone know how to solve it in the code, so that the Icon appears within the select options?

Code:

```
                  {wifiNetwork.map((option, index) => (
                  <option key={index} value={option.network_name}>
                    {option.network_name}
                    {option.signal_strength >= 0 && option.signal_strength < 25 ? (
                      <BiWifi0/>
                    ) : (
                      <BiWifi/>
                    )}
                  </option>
                ))}
```

I need to do Put the Signal Strength Icons Wifi next to the network name:

It only works for now if I put a String in place of the SVG, because according to the suggestion of this topic: [Suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596240/svg-inside-option-element), the option tag only accepts plain text, but they did not make clear a possible alternative. Would it be styling a proper CSS for these Icon?

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this in code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list

Comment: Thanks for your Suggest @CBroe. But This code isn't working not in Firefox or Chrome. Feature not supported. And my svg i m getting in https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/search?q=biwifi.

Comment: Some of the responses in that thread include the suggestion that you might need to use a custom select replacement, if what you want is simply not achievable using the current state of technology regarding native select fields ...

Comment: An alternative could be to use an actual icon _font_, instead of SVGs. Then you could place the corresponding _character_ at the beginning of your option text. (Although it would have to be a font then, that doesn't use any "normal" characters that might occur in your network names - you only get "one text" inside the options that you can format, so you'd have to apply the icon font, and then rely on the browser automatically using a fallback font for any characters, for which the icon font doesn't contain a glyph ...)

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestions @CBroe. I believe I will use this mentioned alternative. I will try to implement it. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem I had to use a React component. React Select, using this example:

[Example Using React Select Component](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-label-icon-thngm?file=/src/index.js)

It was possible to work around the problem, because with this component it displays the Icons, as they are not within an option tag.

My code:

```
const listValues = () => {
return (
  wifiNetwork &&
  wifiNetwork.map(option => {
    let signal = null;
    if (option.signal_strength !== 0) signal = <BiWifiOff/>;
    if (option.signal_strength === 100) signal = <GrWifi/>;
    const value = {
      value: option.network_name,
      label: (
        <>
          {signal}
          <span style={{ paddingRight: '5px' }}>&nbsp;{option.network_name}</span>
        </>
      ),
    };
    return value;
  })
);};

           <div className="rg-select">
              <div className="rg-select-component">
                <label className="rg-select-label">Wifi Networks</label>
                <Select
                  options={listValues()}
                  placeholder="Select Wifi Network" />
              </div>
            </div>
```

I believe that would be a possibility to work around this problem. Other means would be to use Unicodes in the code, but I was worried about browser support.